# Robocode libraries cannot be found by Robot upon runtime

Tags: java, intellij-idea, robocode

I have the programming game 'Robocode' in my project root so I can run the project anywhere and not have it installed in C:/robocode. I have a run configuration with the following options;

- **Main Class:** robocode.Robocode
- **VM Options:** -Xmx512M -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Ddebug=true -DNOSECURITY=true -cp libs/robocode.jar
- **Working directory:** MY_ROOT\robocode_master
- **JRE:** Default(9.0.1 - SDK of my main module)

I'm writing some custom functionality for an AdvancedRobot that connects to a MongoDBAtlas Cluster for necessary data. I'm using mongo-java-driver-3.6.1. The .jar has been added as a library to IntelliJ, then as a compile dependency on the main module. It works fine in testing, I can download documents etc.

To illustrate, the libraries are shown here in the Project structure pane.

[image: Project Structure]

I have set the compile output path to the **robocode_master/robots** directory so that when I run Robocode from IntelliJ, it will see the custom robot .class files in the correct directory and allow me to add them to a battle.

The problem is when I start the battle and the robot tries to do what it needs to do, it throws a **java.io.FileNotFoundException** and is trying to find the necessary library files from the **robocode_master/robots** directory.

For example, the first thing it does is connect to the DB;

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MY_ROOT\robocode_master\robots\com\mongodb\MongoClient.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

When I have my project output paths set to the robots folder, upon launching Robocode, it throws a bunch of FileNotFoundExceptions. But if I switch the options to 'Inherit project compile output path', then launch Robocode, I don't get the exceptions upon launch. But now of course, my robots aren't in the default directory, so it can't see them. So I add the new path in **out/production/...** to Robocode in the GUI and reboot, and I then get the same exceptions from the robots. It now tries to look for the files in **out/production/.../com/mongodb/MongoClient.class**

How can I 'tell' Robocode to look for the libraries in their default location on the classpath?

Comment: I am not at home right now and don't think I can really help with that (I have had similar classpath problems with Robocode in the past and I think there might be some problem with its handling). But have you tried adding the correct path to the VM options' `-cp` argument?

Comment: I’ve added the correct path to the robocode.jar with the -cp argument. So the game launches successfully, it’s the paths to my module libraries that cannot be found.

Comment: Oh, I meant adding the path to your module libraries to the `-cp` (semicolon-separated after the `robocode.jar`). But it might not work (it "kind of" worked for me and my problem, but I had different errors back then).

Comment: Ah, I understand. Would I add that to the VM Options in the Application Run Configuration (That starts Robocode) ?

Comment: Yes, in your run configuration (the **"VM Options""* line at the top of your post). But as I said: don't get your hopes up. Someone else might know more though, I'm not much of a Java developer. AFAIK Robocode has a self-built class loader that might work in mysterious ways. It's Open Source, so you could always have a look at the Robocode source to find out more.

Comment: Semicolon separating paths doesn't seem to work. I've tried moving all the relevant .jar files to the working directory in the **robocode_master** and adding their paths to the `-cp` argument. But the IntelliJ throws `Error: Could not find or load main class libs.robocode.jar Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: libs.robocode.jar`, for example.

Comment: Why is it `libs.robocode.jar` instead of a / or \ between `libs` and `robocode.jar`?

Comment: Unsure, the paths in the VMOptions have forward slashes, any path I use ends up with the . separating it in the console output. I renamed all the jars to single word, lowercase. `libs/mongo.jar` but the console then cannot find `libs.mongo.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Robocode will look for robot classes in your /robots folder. If your robot is located somewhere else, you need to tell Robocode where to locate these from the Robocode UI by setting with the [Developments Options](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode/Add_a_Robot_Project). Robocode has it's own class loader for loading Robot classes - but only robot classes.

Other classes/libraries must be specified on the ordinary classpath for Robocode using the -cp or -classpath for the java command (VM Options) like done for any other Java application.

Also notice, that you should use the VM Options that comes with Robocode - like the ones specified in the robocode.bat file. Especially when you use Java 9 or newer:

```
java -Xmx512M -cp libs/robocode.jar -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions "--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED" robocode.Robocode %*
```

You could copy this into "run_my_stuff.bat" and add stuff to the -cp right after libs/robocode.jar.

However, I am not sure if it will work with the Mongo driver. Robocode was built for simple robots with limited access to resources like CPU cycles, file access etc.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I have set the output folder to the `/robots` folder. The robots are loaded successfully, they just cannot invoke any methods from class in the libraries due to the FileNotFound Exceptions. I'm trying a new approach using the package control method. Now I'm getting an `invalid robot or team` error when loading my own robots. I've posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robocode/srza4x8R7oE) on the Google group.